# WCF AsyncPattern and masstransit request/response

Tags: wcf, masstransit

I try to implement an Asynchronous Service Operation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx) with masstransit request/response.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginMyOperation(string data, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

    string EndMyOperation(IAsyncResult result);
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    private string _answer;

    public IAsyncResult BeginMyOperation(string data, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
        return Bus.Instance.BeginPublishRequest(
            new MyRequestMessage { Data = data }, callback, asyncState, cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.Handle<MyResponseMessage>(c => _answer = c.Answer);
                    cfg.SetTimeout(5.Seconds());
                });
    }

    public string EndMyOperation(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Bus.Instance.EndPublishRequest<MyResponseMessage>(result);
        return _answer;
    }
}
```

But EndPublishRequest throws an Exception "The argument is not an IRequest". Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the exception message needs to be a bit better, if you look at the signature though:

```
public static bool EndPublishRequest<TRequest>(this IServiceBus bus, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

it becomes apparent that the **request** message type is the required type arg here.